# Add prefix to all class names in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

i aim to append prefix to each class name in my code. So i want `class="text-black border-b p-2 border-gray-100 flex justify-between"` to become `class="tw-text-black tw-border-b tw-p-2 tw-border-gray-100 tw-flex tw-justify-between"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this find and replace:

Find: `(?<=class="[^"]*)([^\s"]+)`
Replace: `tw-$1`

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zauGBn/1).

That uses a non-fixed length positive lookbehind (due to the `*` which can be any number) - so that regex **will work** in vscode's Find widget but not in the Search across files input.  So only one file at a time.

Then the idea is to get all blocks that do not contain a space or `"` as a group `$1`.